# Why does the ActionBar not show when I extend from ListActivity instead of ActionBarActivity?

Tags: java, android

When I change the activity to extend from `ListActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` the action bar is removed.

`public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {`

changed to:

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {`

**Contents of activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
         />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When you do not extend from ActionBarActivity,the Action Bar **will not** show.While your code says one thing,the text says the oppostie.Can you explain the problem a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

`ListActivity` extends from `Activity`, not `ActionBarActivity`. When you extend `ListActivity` you are not extending `ActionBarActivity`. Your activity need to extend `ActionBarActivity` to have action bar.

Try extend `ActionBarActivity` and use a [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html) for list content instead.